# Excel - Swap 0 and 1 over

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with a column of `1` or `0` values

I would like to swap the `1` for a `0`
and swap the `0` for a `1`
for every value in that column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to replace the values in the same column, you will need to use either `FIND/REPLACE` or a VBA macro.

If you want to use a helper column, you can use the formula:

```
B1: =N(NOT(A1=1))
```

and fill down.

[image]

If you have O365 with dynamic arrays, you can use the formula:

```
B1: =N(BITXOR(A1:An,1))
```

and the results will Spill down from row 1 to row `n`

Answer (score 2):

Use Search and Replace

1. Select the entire column
2. Ctrl+H fill in
3. 'Find what' & 'Replaced with' per instructions below
4. Replace all tab (this will replace just within your selection which is your column that you've already selected)

First set aside the 1s

1. F=1
2. R=X

Change the 0s to 1s

1. F=0
2. R=1

Change the original 1s, now Xs, to 0s

1. F=X
2. R=1

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to swap and run this short macro:

```
Sub swap()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = IIf(r.Value = 0, 1, 0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Macros are the gold standard**:  they do what you want, when you want, how you want. Short ones are even better.

If your boss would be upset at you using a macro, copy it into a different spreadsheet, then copy it over to this one when needed, run it, delete it, and no one's the wiser.

If you want to do this, or just want to know a generic not-a-macro method for when you have a small issue, like changing column headings that have years in them when the new year rolls in, or this particular issue, that generic solution using `Find and Replace` is:

1. Use it to change one value to some third value, like A, which cannot be affected by the next operation (so don't change 1's to 10's, then change 0's...).
2. Use it to change the other original value to its actual new value.
3. Use it to change the first one you changed to its actual new value.

So change the 1's to A's, then the 0's to 1's, then the A's to 0's.

Works for all kinds of this class of thing. Your accounting software has a customer called AA001 and someone else called AA002 and you need them reversed? Make AA001 KM001, then AA002 AA001, and finally, KM001 AA002. Same concept applies to surprisingly many arenas.

Comment: This doesn't really give new information compared to existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(NOT(A2=1),"1","0")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145924)